Как скачать Greenplum Database для RHEL 8?
Мне нужно поднять Greenplum на рабочей машине для нужд разработки/тестирования. На github проект архивирован бинарник не получить. https://network.pivotal.io/api/v2/products/pivotal-gpdb/releases/634870/product_files/865717/download выдает что нужен токен.
Есть способ получить rpm пакет Greenplum для Rhel 8 желательно Greenplum 7.x ?

Есть не .rpm, но .tar.gz - от GlowByte, которая выложила дистрибутивы GreenPlum 6.24.6 и 6.25.3 здесь (в т.ч. для Rhel 8) - в статье сообщала, что планируют выложить версию GreenPlum 7.1 позднее.
Ещё существует компания Arenadata, которая как понял делает свою БД на основе Greenplum (их репозиторий) - может быть будет полезно.
